# How to reverse error code in Makefile

Tags: grep, make, exit-status

I want to test if file contain a pattern (skipped jasmine tests that should make my build fail, when run from travis).

I have code like this:

```
skipped_tests:
    $(if $(shell grep -E 'iit|ddescribe' spec/terminalSpec.js), @false, @true)
```

the problem is that I don't get output from `grep`, when it find the lines that match the pattern. I want this so I can see what line caused the issue in travis build log. Is there a way to reverse a command error code (return 0 when non 0 is returned and vice versa)?

I've also tried this:

```
skipped_tests:
    grep -E 'iit|ddescribe' spec/terminalSpec.js
    @test $$? -eq 0 # should it be -ne
```

but this echos one line that have `iit` and doesn't fail, and if it doesn't find the line, then it fails on grep.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/367069/537980

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
skipped_tests:
    @! grep -E 'iit|ddescribe' spec/terminalSpec.js
```

Comment: I've tried !grep but it turns out you need to put space before command. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved the issue by calling grep two times

```
skipped_tests:
    @grep -E 'iit|ddescribe' spec/terminalSpec.js || true
    $(if $(shell grep -E 'iit|ddescribe' spec/terminalSpec.js), @false, @true)
```

is there a better way?

I've tried few other things but it seems that make is operating on strings (use str.replace on Makefile or something) because if output of grep is line of source code it give syntax error from other possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

Define variable at top of `Makefile` and use `ifeq`. For example:

```
RESULT = $(shell grep ... 2>/dev/null && echo 0 || echo 1)
. . .
skipped_tests:
ifeq ($(RESULT),0)
    . . .
endif
```

But `grep` will be executed in every call of `make`, even if skipped_tests isn't calling. If that target is called every time, then it's also solution.

---

Considering you wishes. If you want to use `grep` result in target several times you can use multiline expression. Suppose I have next `Makefile`:

```
all: target

target:
    @res=`grep -E 'test|pttern' test.js` || { res="" ; : ; } ; \
        [ ! -z "$$res" ] && echo "Grep result: $$res" ; \
        ls ; \
        [ ! -z "$$res" ] && echo "Grep result: $$res" ; \
    :

.PHONY: target
```

and I have next `test.js` in the same directory:

```
$ cat test.js
pattern
```

If pattern isn't match there is will be next result:

```
$ make
Makefile  test.js
```

If the pattern is exists there is will be next result:

```
$ make
Grep result: pattern
Makefile  test.js
Grep result: pattern
```

For readability you can change ``` `` ``` with `res=$$(grep -E ...) || ...`.

Of course it's not very convenient to make multiline commands in one call to system (this multiline is one session of interpreter) but sometimes might be useful in cases where you need to operate one variable (environment variable too).

Comment: it would require to run grep each time I call make not only for skipped_tests. and If I would like to have output of grep in terminal I will need to call grep once again.

Comment: @jcubic: I update my answer. Please review.